# Carriage return in raw python string

Tags: python, regex, carriage-return

For some experiments with syntax highlighting, I create the following raw string in **Python 3.6** (please note that the string itself contains a snippet of C-code, but that's not important right now):

```
    myCodeSample = r"""#include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        char arr[5] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};

        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            printf(arr[i]);
        }
        return 0;
    }"""
```

I have noticed that each line ends in a Unix-style `\n` newline character. But I actually want - for the sake of my experiment - to have every line ending in the Windows-style `\r\n` newline character. Is there a way to do this elegantly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just define your string as you're doing, but apply `replace` on the literal:

```
myCodeSample = r"""#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char arr[5] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf(arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}""".replace("\n","\r\n")
```

Comment: Just for my understanding what the actual use of `"""`? Just for having line breaks?

Comment: yes. Triple quotes allow to put line breaks & quotes. Adding raw prefix to that allows almost everything (except triple quotes of course!).